# Checking value via local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm working on a basic browser game engine which stores variables using local storage.

On one html page, I have :

```
localStorage.setItem("money", 49);
```

Then on another page, I want to be able to add 1 to the value. To do this I have the following code on an html page :

```
onClick="varPlus1('money')"
```

and this in the javascript file :

```
function varPlus1(name)

{

    var val=localStorage.getItem(name);

    val += 1;

    localStorage.setItem(name, val);

}
```

I was hoping this would increase the value of the variable 'money' to 50, but it doesn't seem to alter it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Convert val to int, then do '+' then call setItem with new value. Code: localStorage.setItem('money', parseInt(localStorage.getItem('money')) + 1)

Comment: Or just `var val = +localStorage.getItem(name);`

Comment: @RayonDabre  way are better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LocalStorage stores values as `string` and `+= 1` will concatenate strings than doing `add` operation.

`+`(unary plus) will cast `string` to `Number`

Try this:

```js
localStorage.setItem("money", 49);

function varPlus1(name) {
  var val = +localStorage.getItem(name);
  val += 1;
  localStorage.setItem(name, val);
}
varPlus1('money')
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code tested and worked :-
**HTML**

```
<button id="btnSave">sadsadsad</button>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
localStorage.setItem("money", 49);

  $("#btnSave").click(
            function () {
                varPlus1('money');
            }            
        );
});
function varPlus1(name)
{
    var val=localStorage.getItem(name);

    val =parseInt(val)+ 1;

    localStorage.setItem(name, val);
alert (localStorage.getItem(name));
}
```